# Regex for word with fixed number of wildcard characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a pattern that, given the know position of a few characters in a string, will match words that fit that pattern.

For instance: given the string `a*b*****`, I'd like to find `albacore, albahaca, ...`

Using quantifiers following a wildcard (`^a.b.{5}`) doesn't do the trick, and neither does `^a.b\w{5}`

EDIT: I'm using grep to search through a file containing alphabetically sorted words, where each word is on a new line. So the (ineffective) expressions I'm using look like: `grep "^a.b.{5}" words`

Comment: Regex semantics depend on implementation. You need to say exactly what language or library is interpreting your regexes.

Comment: It looks like your regex does not match your sample strings because albacore and albahaca only have 5 characters instead of 6 after the b. Hint: `(a.b.{5,6})`